# Why do I have a tumbleweed badge?

Tags: support, badges

I just checked my profile here and I have a tumbleweed badge. The description for the badge goes:

> Asked a question with zero score, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week.

However, I have never asked any questions here. I am a lurker, I only ever created a profile to upvote a few questions and answers that I like.

So how come I got that weed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [badge details page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed?userid=57616), you apparently asked the question [Controller remapping in Assassin's Creed: Liberation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/201946/controller-remapping-in-assassins-creed-liberation) back in 2015. This question is +0/-0, and was deleted by Community in January 2016 (RemoveAbandonedQuestions)

Comment: Thanks :) I had forgotten about that and couldn'd find anything through my profile.